# Log Stash, multiple grok associated with multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'd like to ask about this scenario.

I have 2 grok patterns to match.

If the first one matches, I would like to associate it with the first index output such as "logstash-business-error".

if the second grok matches, I would like to link it to the second index output such as "logstash-system-error"

Could we make it with logstash.conf?

Below is the current one I have so far which just has 1 index.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
        grok {
           match => {
                    "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} *%{LOGLEVEL:messagetype} (?:\[%{GREEDYDATA:jmsListener}\]) %{WORD:class } - %{WORD:Task} - %{QS:errorType} %{NUMBER:clientlayout}  %{DATA:roll
Up} %{DATA:docName} %{NUMBER:errorNo} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
                  }
            }
            if [messagetype]!="ERROR"{
            drop {}
            }
            date {
            match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
   }




output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       manage_template => false
       index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
       document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
       }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   }
```

Thanks,

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals, use the `=~` on the message to separate the two categories, then add a tag to each to be able to distinguish them at the output.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the trick as below:

Add a new field as

```
mutate {
    add_field => {
            "index_prefix" => "logstash" 
    }
}
if [messagetype]!="ERROR" {
    mutate {
        replace => {
                "index_prefix" => "whateveryouwant" 
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you output using index_prefix as default index

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       manage_template => false
       index => "%{index_prefix}-%{+xxxx.ww}"
       document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
       }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   }
```

The full example is this

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
        grok {
           match => {
                    "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} *%{LOGLEVEL:messagetype} (?:\[%{GREEDYDATA:jmsListener}\]) %{WORD:class } - %{WORD:Task} - %{QS:errorType} %{NUMBER:clientlayout}  %{DATA:roll
Up} %{DATA:docName} %{NUMBER:errorNo} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
                  }
            }
            if [messagetype]!="ERROR"{
            drop {}
            }
            date {
            match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
   }
mutate {
    add_field => {
            "index_prefix" => "logstash" 
    }
}
if [messagetype]!="ERROR" {
    mutate {
        replace => {
                "index_prefix" => "whateveryouwant" 
        }
    }
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       manage_template => false
       index => "%{index_prefix}-%{+xxxx.ww}"
       document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
       }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   }
```